# Why bother with server-side form submissions in a SPA?

Tags: javascript, web, server-side

I am all in favour of progressive enhancement and using server-side rendering when fetching a URL. The age-old discussion gives several advantages, such as improved load time, SEO crawling and possibly an improved level of "correctness"...etc

However I am getting my doubts as to why I am also setting up my server-side to handle form submits (i.e. a [native HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) being submitted to the server).

While my question is generic, the technology stack I am using is a Universal React + Redux application connecting to a third-party API. Therefore when JavaScript is disabled the server-side connects to the API to retrieve or POST data, while when JavaScript is enabled the user's browser connects to the API directly.

What are the advantages in handling server-side POST or when should it be a priority?

Comment: We don't know what your application does. Is there security required? Data integrity required?

Comment: The application in question is an authenticated back office, similar to a CRM; however I am looking at the generic application. I updated the question with some details of the implementation.

Comment: Are you familiar with the properties Idempotent, safe and cacheable? [HTTP methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: `Therefore when JavaScript is disabled the server-side connects to the API to retrieve or POST data, while when JavaScript is enabled the user's browser connects to the API directly.` -- Doesn't that answer the question you posed?

Comment: @Laiv There is a difference between the HTTP method POST (such as what is used to update a model in a RESTful API) and a POST method in an HTML form: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: @RobertHarvey should I be concerned about the fraction of users that don't have JavaScript though? Supporting SSR when fetching data has other consumers other than users with disabled JS, such as screenreaders; while submitting data does not. (or at least I am missing it)

Comment: I don't know.  Only you can answer that question.  As recently as a couple of years ago, some developers were still worrying about supporting Internet Explorer 6.

Comment: `There is a difference between the HTTP method POST (such as what is used to update a model in a RESTful API) and a POST method in an HTML form`. Not really. One possible difference is that Form sends a different Content-Type. Nothing to do with REST. Which could send the very same Content-Type aswell

Comment: The question aims to address the why not the if. Why should I, not if I should.

Comment: @laiv I rephrased the title slightly. My question was not specific to the HTTP verb but form submission (regardless of the verb). I used post originally to differentiate between fetching data and submitting data but that might have created misunderstanding.

Answer (score -1):

One use case where server-side is necessary is when the POST response is a format which is not supported by the client, such as an [ODF](https://blogs.loc.gov/thesignal/2016/01/odf-the-open-document-format/) or [ePub](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/) document. In order to download the file, submitting the data is required.

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either inline (default value, indicating it can be display inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or attachment (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present).

```
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.odf"
```

**References**

- [Content-Disposition - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: You can actually initiate a download from JS and specify the request to be made with http method and everything else

Comment: @marstato As you can see in either the [POST](https://www.aconvert.com/ebook/djvu-to-rtf/) or [GET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format) based API requests, the response requires an additional step to download.